# IE9 Quirks Mode issue? SP 2010!

Tags: 2010, internet-explorer, browser-compatibility

I work on a 2010 intranet (foundation) site, which over the past year has been working fine and dandy (the company uses ie8). Now faced with possibly moving up to IE9 due to some software upgrades, I've updated my IE8 to IE9 and have been getting some weirdness which I cannot figure out how to get around.

I open IE which defaults to our sharepoint homepage and it renders in IE9 Quirks mode! I hit refresh and a this point it renders to IE8 Standards mode.

My question is, does this really mean Sharepoint 2010 isn't compatible with IE9? I've tried all sorts of combinations changing the doctypes from HTML, to strict, to transitional, changing the meta X-UA-compatible tag from IE=8 to IE=9 to IE=EDGE, and nothing is preventing IE9 from loading the page in Quirks mode.

Does anyone know what this issue is caused by, and what options are there out there? is it necessary to go to the 2013 version of Sharepoint to avoid this? or is it simply some code in the masterpage that I need to add?

Comment: I'm running SP2010 in IE9 and it works fine in standard mode.  If I force IE9 Quirks mode (via F12 developer tools) the page doesn't even render correctly.  I'm wondering if you've done some customizations that are throwing things off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to service pack 2, SharePoint 2010 is not compatible with IE9.  By default, the masterpage should force IE8 mode.  I read somewhere that SP2 was making 2010 compatible with modern browsers but I do not remember seeing this confirmed.

Comment: Here (http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_sustained_engineering/archive/2013/07/16/office-2010-and-sharepoint-2010-service-pack-2-availability.aspx) they state that yes, SP2 should  improve the compatibility with Windows 8 and Internet Explorer 10 (not sure if this inherently means that the compatibility with IE9 is also improved)